# What do upper bound and lower bound mean?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am confused with upper and lower bound in algorithm complexity. For example, if ()=(2), ()=Ω(^-1). Can I say that there always exists n^-1≤T(n)≤2n ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot draw this conclusion. The correct statement is that there exist constants C1, C2 > 0 such that for large enough n (n > some constant n0)

```
C1 * (n^-1) ≤ T(n) ≤ C2 * n
```